# # in Material Description for some materials which is causing alignment issue in SAP ABAP

Tags: abap, sap-gui, sap-erp, non-printing-characters

How to take out # from Material Description ? and anyone know why # exists in some materials.

Comment: Can you post an image of that description?

Comment: What do you mean with "take out"? Do you want to prevent users from entering them? In which transaction? Do you want to remove them from your existing data? Do you want to keep them in the database but not have them show up on the UI? In which transactions specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes user copy/paste texts from internet/email and paste it to SAP GUI. So some characters not saved/displayed correctly and SAP replace them with #.

You can use **ES_REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER** FM for removing special characters. Also you can create your own with TRANSLATE command.

```
TRANSLATE lv_string USING '# @ £ § ! & '.
```

Comment: This might explain how those characters might have gotten in the material descriptions, but not how to get rid of them.

Comment: You can create your own clearing perform. Also a lot of companies have master data management and in that process they clean this type of mistakes, spell checking etc.

Comment: Can you explain how do do that in your answer?